# MVC Parital view ID to render another partival view

Tags: view, model

My MVC page has a Parent view that show the Parish page. Every Parish has multiple Churches and Every Church has its Own mass times. Parish page has Churches as Partial View but I want to use Church ID to render another Parital view of Mass times (Stored Procidure). How can use the ID of a partial view and create anothe partial view. I had been banging my head but unable to get this resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working... I was now able to get the Partial view work...

**Stored Procedure inside the controller:**

```
    public ActionResult Timing(int id)
    {
        var massTimings = db.masTimings(id);

         return PartialView(massTimings);
    }
```

**My View inside Locations Partial View:**

@Html.Action("Timing",new {id = item.LocationID})

Answer (score 0):

render the Partial view in Side the Div tag. Then use the div ID and Clone the div to create a another partial view.
 See below code sample.

```
<Div id="SomeId">
 //Render your partial view here.
</Div>
```

Clone the Div and create as many partial view u need.